# Как ограничить кол-во страниц в пагинации?modx

Tags: modx, pagination, пагинация

При адаптации сайта, пагинация портит всю малину, как выводит все страницы(или большое кол-во) где можно исправить это? modx

Answer (score 0):

Если для пагинации вы используете [pdoPage](https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdopage), обратите внимание на ajax параметры, можно подгружать объекты по мере надобности.

Answer (score 0):

Если используете `pdoPage` там надо указывать 2 параметра:

```
[[!pdoPage?
        &limit=`200`
        &maxLimit=`200`
        ...
]]
```

где:

`&limit` - Ограничение количества результатов на странице. Число должно быть больше 0, иначе вам не нужен этот сниппет.

`&maxLimit` - Максимально возможный лимит выборки. Перекрывает лимит, указанный пользователем через url.

В примере будет вывод 200 элементов на странице

чанк `[[!+page.nav]]` использовать не надо, это блок для вывода номеров страниц

Для сниппета `getPage` все тоже самое, только не надо указывать `&maxLimit` - там такого параметра нет

Comment: нет, не через сниппет,эх

Comment: тогда расширьте свой вопрос, как делается пагинация, чтобы знать как вам помочь